# Is it possible to generate scenario outline definition dynamically

Tags: karate

Is it possible to generate the scenario outline definition dynamically by calling a method in karate. In the following example

```
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs <input>

Examples:
      | res |
```

suppose value of res is:

```
[
   input: {test: "xyz"},
   input: {test: "pqr"},
   input: {test: "abc"}
]
```

The actual object inside input is quite complex, just simplified it for example.

In this case I want by different scenario definition to be

```
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs xyz
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs pqr
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs abc
```

Is this possible?

Comment: in my opinion, yes. refer linked answer. note that you can even use a function to "generate" data that will get exploded into multiple `Scenario`-s. please refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-function-data-source

Comment: @PeterThomas yea this I got, actually my scenarios are working fine, it is exploding into multiple scenarios, just that the scenario definition shown in the console in printing like this 

`Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs {test: "xyz"}
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs {test: "pqr"}
Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs {test: "abc"}`
I was just wondering if i can call a function here to extract the 'test' property or any other nested key in the complex object. I tried calling a function there but it was not working

Comment: something like this
`* def getNames = function() {}`
`Scenario Outline: Testing different combination of inputs {call getNames res}`

Comment: your question was confusing. so you mean the "name as it appears in the report" yes, look for this in the docs: `Scenario Outline: name is ${name.first} ${name.last} and age is ${age}` https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements